# Query for segments at same place and time in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, buffer, intersection

I've imported the segments of several GPX-Tracks in a PostGIS-Table. Now I'm looking for a query that returns all segments that:

1. are spatially overlapping (within a specific buffer-distance) and
2. at about the same time.

I've tried to use `ST_Intersects`, `ST_Buffer` and standard SQL-queries for the time-aspect. Alas, no attempt was successful.

Does someone have a hint how such a query could look like?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you use [ST_HausdorffDistance()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html) to caluclate the similarity of your GPS tracks; using `ST_Buffer()` or `ST_Distance()` will cause you issues if your tracks get near to each other at some point, but otherwise are divergent.

Hausdorff distance is a bit funny to get your head around, but it's ideal for this sort of query, and after a bit of trial and error, you can usually settle on a good value for what you consider similar.

The time part of the query can be best handled with the `TIMESTAMP` and `INTERVAL` types built in to PostgreSQL. Assuming you have one row per track, and each track has a single `TIMESTAMP` representing the start time say, then queries like these work well:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1999-12-30' - TIMESTAMP '1999-12-11' < INTERVAL '20 days';
```

Which returns true;

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1999-12-30' - TIMESTAMP '1999-12-11' < INTERVAL '20 minutes';
```

Which returns false.

So your overall query should look something like this:

```sql
SELECT a.geom FROM gps a, gps b
  WHERE ST_HausdorffDistance(a.geom, b.geom) < 23.0
  AND b.ts <= a.ts
  AND a.ts - b.ts < INTERVAL '20 minutes';
```

So we're checking for the similarity of two linestrings, then only if one timestamp is less than another (to avoid two records being compared on both sides) do we see if they're temporally similar.

Caveat: I've not tried this on real data, but the syntax works on my database.